# 'incorrect credentials' error when using Netbeans to connect to azure devops GIT repository

Tags: git, netbeans, azure-devops, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to connect to an azure devops repository in Netbeans, but my credentials are not accepted:

[image: netbeans]

It has worked before in Netbeans like this. And when I use GIT on command line it also works (btw on command line I get a popup from Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows, which handles the connection to azure devops).

I also changed the GIT pasword in the DevOps project just to be sure...

I'm using Repository URL like this:
`https://dev.azure.com/my_organization/my_project/_git/repo_name`

Any ideas how to fix this ?

**Update:**

I also tried the following:

- first I remove all DevOps items in > Control Panel > Windows Vault
- then on command line I execute > git pull, and I get a popup from Visual Studio (= Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows)
- in this popup I remove the existing account just to be sure, but then when I add it again it never asks for the password, which I find strange
- when I select the account then authentication succeeds, and pull works
- if I do git pull a second time, then it works without popup because (I think because credentials are saved in Windows Vault)
- when I **don't** use the GCM popup by closing it, then the password is asked on the command line, but then authentication **fails**

[image: wincred]

[image: command]

[image: command2]

Comment: try `https://dev.azure.com/my_organization/my_project/_git/repo_name.git/`

Comment: adding `.git` gives the same result: Incorrect credentials for etc ...

Comment: Can you get the address of the repository from azure (not the URL where you see it but the URL where it is reachable). Is it reachable from HTTPS or do you have to use ssh? Is there a firewall, have you used your user/password somewhere else and have verified that they work?

Comment: I have no problems in connecting to azure DevOps using Visual Basic on the same project (but differen repo). And as already mentioned I can also connect using command line without problems (then GCM popup comes up and handles credentials). See update in question.

Comment: did you get answer?